# Local time to UTC

Tags: date, time

Is it possible to convert a list of local time into UTC?The list of local time is in a text file and I want it to create another text file with a list but in UTC. If possible what command could help

Local time(PST)

```
year
month 
day 
hour 
min 
sec

2016  03   01  13   15  00

2016  05   12  16   01  22

2016  12   23  09   11  11
```

Above is a sample format inside of a text file.

Comment: What I knew UTC = GMT.My time is UTC+7 = GMT+7. London's time is GMT+0

Comment: @supriady London's time is not always `GMT`, it is `BST = GMT+1` during the daylight saving period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic command is `date`.  For your first date, you could type in

```
date -u --date=2016-03-01T13:15:00PST
```

Of course you want read the text file, so you could do something like

```
awk '{print "date -u --date="$1"-"$2"-"$3"T"$4":"$5":"$6"PST"}' file.txt | sh
```

And there are plenty of other ways to process the text file.  The `man` page for `date` has info on how to format the output.

Comment: Requires GNU `date`.

Comment: It's actually almost achievable with BSD `date` as well.  The `%Z` specifier to the `-f` option does not like "PST" as a timezone, though.

Comment: @JdeBP and no `--date` option.

Comment: I suggest a re-visit of the BSD `date` manual.  The GNU `--date` option is _not a problem_.  One supplies the input date string to BSD `date` slightly differently, but it is quite capable of taking dates as input.  After all, it wouldn't be a very good command for setting the system clock otherwise.  (How not to set the system clock is also explained in the BSD `date` manual.  Indeed, it even has examples of how to do a transformation that is quite close to the one being asked for here.  It is _only_ that "PST" isn't a recognized input timezone that is the problem.)

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk` (usually on Linux and sometimes on other systems) and that data you can use

```
[g]awk '{print strftime(fmt,mktime($0" 0"),1)}' file
```

If you want output format the same as input, use `"%Y %m %d %H %M %S"` for fmt. If your input is actually local *civil* time, including daylight/summer time during the appropriate part of the year, omit the `" 0"` suffix. If 'PST' is US Pacific zone then it normally follows US rules for daylight time, but if it is Phillipine time it does not normally shift, being near the equator.